# javascript in <head> tag not working because of the onload event in <body> tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In the `<head>` tag I have a javascript code which is generating a cookie.

Strangely enough when I remove the `onload` event which is in the body, the cookie is generated. When the onload event isnt remove,  the cookie will not be generated. Below please find the code. I think the problem is because of the onload event.

```
<body onload = "changeVal()" > 

<script language="JavaScript">
function changeVal() {
var myForm = document.getElementById('DownloadForm');
myForm.cmbCountries.value = geoip_country_name();

if (geoip_country_name() == 'United Kingdom' || ... )
      {
      $("#MemberCountryOptInchk").show();
      }
  else {
        $("#MemberCountryOptInchk").hide();
      $(".hiddenf").hide();
      $(".hiddenf").attr("disabled", "disabled");   
      $("#MemberCountryOptInchk").attr("disabled", "disabled");  
     }


  if (geoip_country_name() == 'United Kingdom'){

      $("#cmbcounty").show();
      $("#cmbCounty").show();
      $("#cmbCounty").focus();
      $("#cmbCounty").attr("disabled", "");
      $("#cmbcounty").attr("disabled", "");   



  }
  else if (geoip_country_name() == 'United States'){

      $("#cmbstate").show();
      $("#cmbStateus").show();
      $("#cmbStateus").focus();
      $("#cmbStateus").attr("disabled", "");
      $("#cmbstate").attr("disabled", "");
  }


  else if (geoip_country_name() == 'Australia'){

      $("#cmbaus").show();
      $("#cmbAus").show();
      $("#cmbAus").focus();
      $("#cmbAus").attr("disabled", "");
      $("#cmbaus").attr("disabled", "");
  }




 else if (geoip_country_name() == 'Canada'){

      $("#cmbstateca").show();
      $("#cmbStateca").show();
      $("#cmbStateca").focus();
      $("#cmbStateca").attr("disabled", "");
      $("#cmbstateca").attr("disabled", "");
  }

  else if (geoip_country_name() != 'Canada' || geoip_country_name() != 'United States' || geoip_country_name() != 'United Kingdom'  || geoip_country_name() != 'Australia' ) {

    $("#cmbStateus").hide();
    $("#cmbstate").hide();
    $("#cmbStateus").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    $("#cmbstate").attr("disabled", "disabled");



    $("#cmbAus").hide();
    $("#cmbaus").hide();       
    $("#cmbAus").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    $("#cmbaus").attr("disabled", "disabled");

    $("#cmbStateca").hide();
    $("#cmbstateca").hide();       
    $("#cmbStateca").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    $("#cmbstateca").attr("disabled", "disabled");


    $("#cmbCounty").hide();
    $("#cmbcounty").hide();
    $("#cmbCounty").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    $("#cmbcounty").attr("disabled", "disabled");    

  } 
}
</script>
```

Comment: Are there any errors in the console when the script is put in the body `onload`?

Comment: no....I am using firebug to check this.

Comment: How does the code in the `head` look like?

Comment: Unrelated, but you should definitely use a `switch` statement :). Related : we have no information about your `head` code.

Comment: The code you posted generates no cookie. It just shows/hides and disable some elements. Please post relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like stating the obvious, but have you tried calling your **ChangeVal()** function from

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   //Hallelujah
   changeVal() 
 });
```

Instead of doing an *onLoad* inside your *body* attribute. This will even help you in case you want to call more functions upon the loading of the DOM.